# Docker unreachable after computer sleep

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10, docker-toolbox

I have just installed docker using [docker-toolbox 1.8.2](https://www.docker.com/toolbox) on Windows 10.

Due to [this issue](https://github.com/kitematic/kitematic/issues/386#issuecomment-123804467) I had to recreate the docker image using these commands

```
docker-machine rm default
docker-machine --native-ssh create -d virtualbox default
```

After that it has been working fine, except for one problem:

When the PC has gone to sleep and then wakes again, the docker commands can no longer connect. Example:

```
> docker images
An error occurred trying to connect: Get https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.20/images/json: 
dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: ConnectEx tcp: A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection 
failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

However the `docker-machine` lists the machine as running:

```
> docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
```

I can also confirm in VirtualBox that the VM screen seems to be active.

I have tried starting and stopping the machine, but that does not help

```
C:\x> docker-machine stop default
C:\x> docker-machine start default
Starting VM...
Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-machine env` command.
C:\x> docker-machine env default --shell=powershell
```

Ironically, the last command hangs, so I never get any environment settings.

The only thing that helps is to restart the whole PC. But that should be unnecessary?

I have also posted this as [an issue on the docker github repository](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16265),but that was closed. [A related issue seems to be this one](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1500), but no workaround or solution has been posted for Windows.

Comment: Is the container attached to a different network interface than the one used by the operating system? I noticed while running Hyper-V VMs that after the host machine resumes from sleep it only wakes the primary network interface, not the one I had reserved for the VMs. The trick was to disable and then enable that network interface.

Comment: @Petrik The container lists three network interfaces: `docker0`, `eth1` and `lo`.
I am not running Hyper-V. 
I tested disabling/enabling the internet network interface on the host PC but that did not help. Docker has created 4 (four!) network interfaces on the host PC.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is disabling/enabling the docker interfaces on the host PC. No idea what else it could be.

Answer (score 14):

After hous of fighting with VirtualBox + Docker Toolbox, I finally found the way, how to make Docker working again (even without restarting all the containers):

1. Wake up PC from sleep
2. Try `docker images` (won`t work)
3. Open VirtualBox -> Close VM with saving state (CTRL+V)
4. Run your VM again
5. Try `docker images` again (now should work)

Please note: All steps are in VirtualBox only! Running `docker-machine restart default` will create another host-only adapter, which is something you do not want. If you did it anyway, delete all **additionally created adapters** (File->Preferences->Network on VirtualBox), then follow steps 1-5.

Comment: Nice. This worked for me.  Wondering how you figured out to go at VirtualBox rather than Docker?

Comment: Just a wild guess - something like old school 90´s adventure game using "everything on everything". This magically worked.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on Hyper-V and Windows 10. Open Hyper-V > Stop MobyLinuxVM > Settings > Automatic stop action > set to 'Save'.

Answer (score 6):

I have experienced the exact same symptoms on Windows 8.1... The thing is that it's not really a docker-specific issue, but more how Windows manages the VirtualBox network adapters after sleep (I think...). The culprit in my case is that the network adapter's addresses were becoming private after sleep (they became 169.* addresses).

Credits to this guy who gave me the idea: http://lyngtinh.blogspot.ca/2011/12/how-to-disable-autoconfiguration-ipv4.html

Fix:

1. Start a command prompt as Administrator
2. Find out the "useful" network adapters: `ipconfig /all`. The useful ones in my case were the ones labeled "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" that didn't have private ips (not starting with 169.*).
3. Run this command and note the "Idx" of the useful VirtualBox network adapters: `netsh interface ipv4 show inter`.
4. Run this command to disable the IP auto configuration: `netsh interface ipv4 set interface <idx> dadtransmits=0 store=persistent`. Replace <idx> with each index found in the previous step.
5. Restart Windows

Afterwards, I was able to `docker-machine start default`, then `docker-machine env default --shell cmd`, put the PC to sleep, wake up and run `docker-machine env default --shell cmd` again.

Comment: Very nice. I've been trying to fix this for a while now

Answer (score 5):

I found that removing 'host only adapter' (File->Preferences->Network on VirtualBox), and restart the docker-machine helps.

Not a real solution. But probably better over restart the computer.

Comment: Best workaround so far. It also made me clean up the network list, I had four VirtualBox networks, but it seems only one is really used.

Answer (score 2):

Having tried all the other answers here, and having varying but not consistent success, the following seems to reliably bring it back for me after this problem occurs.

Open a powershell/command window (I have most success if I run all docker-machine commands in a powershell window opened as administrator, I don't know if that's important or not) then run (where "dev" is the name of your docker machine instance):

```
docker-machine ssh dev
```

Then on the terminal that is opened, run:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

When the machine restarts, it seems to refresh the network and work correctly. Note, however, that simply running `docker-machine restart dev` did **not** have the same effect for me.

Your machine needs to be running before you can do the ssh, so if it's not running, execute `docker-machine start dev` before trying to SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on Windows 8.1 and docker toolbox 1.12.0
None of the above solutions worked for me, too.

[edited]

Found another way to make docker work after system wake up:

- In the docker Quickstart Terminal window, stop docker process `Ctrl-C` (if it is still running)
- Run command `docker-compose down`
- Shut down docker with `docker-machine stop default`
- Exit terminal window `Ctrl-D`
- Run Quickstart Terminal again and do all subsequent steps you need.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, on Windows host machine.

Configure your network adapter to

1) Allow the network adapter to wake the computer,

2) Allow a magic packet to wake the computer,

3) Allow IPV6

http://www.worldstart.com/dropped-internet-connection-in-sleep-mode/

Also, on virtual box network settings, go to advanced, and allow promiscuous mode to VM machines, or allow all